# Error booting 15.10 (UEFI): "Limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps - Hard resetting link "

Tags: boot, uefi, 15.10, sata

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 along my windows 10 and first it booted in perfectly.
I updated with the auto updater and also the drivers i.e additional drivers. Thus a restart prompt came up. I did a shutdown and change my boot priority to UEFI.

Then I tried to enter back into Ubuntu from boot manager, but now I get this error:

> Limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
>   Hard resetting link

I hold down the power button, went back to boot manager and it booted to windows with no hassle.

Comment: What if you undo changing your boot settings to UEFI? Does Ubuntu boot again then? You may not install Ubuntu in Legacy mode and then switch to UEFI boot later, it has to run in the mode you used to install it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed back as you suggested but it is still the same as before. Is this becoz of updating or I did select amd/ati as my graphic option rather than the open source one. But when I did execute the amdconfig command it did say no such device found

Comment: Yeah, I did a reinstall of ubuntu, everything went fine and at last I installed my amd graphic drivers, now it is in the same state again. I suppose I should revert back to deleting the last change